# "Div hover" is working but not valid (yet)

Tags: javascript, css, html, toggle

I have a problem with this script : [click here](http://www.verkopervinden.nl/test5.html). Currently it's working perfectly. But if i would run this through the w3 validator it's not 'valid'. I also know why this is, it is because the entire div is within a link.

I would like to make this work exactly the same, but also have it score as w3 valid. I have been struggeling for two weeks now with this problem and i (apperently) could use some help with this. Who can help me make this script w3 valid and work exactly like it is working right now.

I would like to keep this in HTML/CSS, i have been trying this in Java as well, but that kept 'flickering' with the mouse over.

Thanks a lot for any help, it is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work in IE6, you will have to keep the `:hover` pseudoclass on the `<a>` tag. In IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and I believe Opera, you can place `:hover` on any tag, and in that case, I would suggest you change the `<a>` tag to a `<div>` tag.

To make it W3C compliant for IE6 functionality, change your `<div>` tags to `<span>` tags and put `display:block;` on the `<span>` tags and the `<a>` tag. That way the functionality should not change and you should become W3C compliant, at least within that section.

Comment: Agreed - but the `a` tags would have to have an absolute height. Or maybe have `div` tags which set the height, then `a` tags with `display: block;` and width / height 100%.

Comment: If i just change the <div> into <span> i get this: http://www.verkopervinden.nl/test6.html and the validator than complaines about <h1> and <p>

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: It shouldn't need an absolute height as long as the new span tags have a height and width set as well as being defined as block elements. In effect, it should do the exact same thing as it is now, as a `span` element is `display:inline` while a `div` is `display:block`.

Comment: @jerry: Make sure you set your spans to `display:block` as well. That should alleviate the issues with it not displaying correctly. Do you have to use `h1` and `p`? If so, you'll have to go with a javascript implementation rather than a CSS implementation.

Comment: I suggest, instead of `h1` and `p`, you use `<span class="h1|paragraph">...</span>` and then set the properties for those classes instead. That would work - and @Jeff Rupert I dont see why anyone would **have** to use particular elements. This technique has never failed me on the occasions I have needed to use it.

Comment: @Jeff and ClarkeyBoy really thanks a lot, for now this does the trick.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: At least in the case of `h1`, there is some SEO benefit that wouldn't exist with the `span` tag. That's the only reason of which I can think that would cause such a requirement. Otherwise, yes, you're 100% correct. @jerry: You're welcome! Glad it was useful to you. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `<a>` tag inside the div, and css'ing it with:

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: The hover effect is than gone, so that's not working. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: It does work if you put the `:hover` on the link instead. I have done this for a menu with block `a` tags in `li` tags - I have a nice hover colour change effect working.

Comment: Well then remove the `<a>` tag, and use `onmouseover` on the `<div>` tags to trigger jQuery's `toggle()` method.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy I don't think that IE supports `:hover` on anything other that `<a>` tags. At least not all versions do.

Comment: @Julio Santos: If you reread my comment I said to put :hover on the **link** instead of the div. This would work with all versions of IE.

Comment: hmm having just read the question properly, and having looked at the script, I dont think it is possible to do this in **just** html and CSS. It may be possible with CSS3 - but if you want it to be cross-browser then that wont work yet. I recommend you either stick with W3 invalid, or that you use jQuery to achieve this effect on link hover. Either way you are not going to be able to satisfy all your requirements.

Comment: @Julio: No worries - even the best of us make mistakes now and then.